# How to set default image when you make a network request and it brings no image?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, networking

So I am making a network request. I parse the JSON to custom Objects. In these objects there are urls which are suppose to bring back images. One of the URL returns an error message (404) so there ins't anything there! How can I set a default image in its place and stop my app from crashing? Here is my code! Thanks

```
import UIKit

class HomepageCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var imageCache = NSCache()
    var hingeImagesArray = [HingeImage]()
    var arrayToHoldConvertedUrlToUIImages = [UIImage]()
    var task: NSURLSessionDataTask?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Makes the network call for HingeImages
        refreshItems()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hingeImagesArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageReuseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

        let image = hingeImagesArray[indexPath.row]

        if let imageURL = image.imageUrl {

            if let url = NSURL(string: imageURL) {

                //settingImageTpChache

                if let myImage = imageCache.objectForKey(image.imageUrl!) as? UIImage {

                    cell.collectionViewImage.image = myImage

                }else {

                 // Request images asynchronously so the collection view does not slow down/lag
                self.task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                        // Check if there is data returned
                        guard let data = data else {
                            return
                        }

                        // Create an image object from our data and assign it to cell


                        if let hingeImage = UIImage(data: data){

                            //cachedImage
                          self.imageCache.setObject(hingeImage, forKey: image.imageUrl!)


                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                           cell.collectionViewImage.image = hingeImage

                            //append converted Images to array so we can send them over to next view - only proble in that the only images converted at the ones you scrool to which is retarted

                            self.arrayToHoldConvertedUrlToUIImages.append(hingeImage)

                            print(self.arrayToHoldConvertedUrlToUIImages)

                             })


                        }
                })

                task?.resume()

                      }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check if error is not nil then set deafult image .

```
self.task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

if error != nil { 
 cell.collectionViewImage.image = UIImage(named:"default_image")
 return 
}
...
```

Comment: do you have default image in xcassests?

Comment: then put it into your project. in case if you don't get any image from web, how would set to default image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {
    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrl(urlString: String) {
        self.image = nil

        // check for cache
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        // download image from url
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            var image:UIImage

            if error == nil {
                if(UIImage(data: data!) != nil){
                    image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                } else {
                    image = UIImage(named: "DefaultImage")!
                }
            } else {
                print(error ?? "load image error")
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                self.image = image
            })
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

The key point is with 404 return message, **data task error is still = nil** and this time you must check `UIImage(data: data!) != nil` to prevent a “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value”